# Interchanging statements in for loop

Tags: c

This is the line of code in C.
The condition of loop here is ++i.
So how does compiler decide which condition to consider because here other two appear as conditions?

```
char i=0;
for(i<=5&&i>-1;++i;i>0)
    printf("%d",i);
```

output

```
1234..127-128-127....-2-1
```

Comment: Note that the behavior of the program is implementation-defined (or potentially undefined) and depends on (among other things) the signedness of the `char` type, the ranges of values representable by `char`, `int`, and `unsigned int`, and the implementation-defined behavior of a narrowing conversion from one signed type to another signed type.  In short:  writing code like this is perilous.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `for` statement works like this:

```
for (X; Y; Z)
{
    ...
}
```

translates to

```
X;
while (Y)
{
    ...
    Z;
}
```

So your code changes from:

```
char i=0;
for(i<=5&&i>-1;++i;i>0)
    printf("%d",i);
```

to:

```
char i = 0;
i<=5 && i>-1;    // X
while (++i)      // Y
{
    printf("%d", i);
    i > 0;       // Z
}
```

As you can see, lines marked with `X` and `Z` are completely useless. Therefore:

```
char i = 0;
while (++i)
    printf("%d", i);
```

This means it will print from 1 up to whenever result of `++i` is zero.

If `char` in your compiler is signed, then the behavior is left to implementation, even though most likely it will overflow to a negative value and work its way up to zero.

If `char` is positive, this will print positive values up to where it overflows back to 0.

Comment: C11, section 3.4.3.3 (EXAMPLE): _An example of undefined behavior is the behavior on integer overflow._

Comment: Nit:  The behavior is only undefined if `char` is signed _and_ all values representable by `int` are also representable by `char` (i.e., if `char` and `int` are represented by the same number of bits).  If `char` is narrower than `int`, then the behavior is implementation-defined because there is no overflow:  the `char` operand will be promoted to `int` to perform the increment, then the `int`-type result will be converted back to `char`; that conversion does not yield overflow, it has implementation-defined behavior.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't. It runs the first part and `i` gets set to any side effect of this, then it terminates when the second part is false, in this case when `i` is 0, then on every loop it runs the 3rd part.

SO the compiler essentially rewrites this as:

```
char i=0;
i<=5&&i>-1;
do {
     printf("%d",i);
     i>0;
} while ( (++i) != 0)
```

hint: remember char is signed and twos complement, so i will go 1,2,3....128, -127,-126.... 0

Comment: "remember char is signed"  or unsigned:  the signedness of char is implementation-defined.

Comment: @JamesMcNellis and needn't be 8bits. But in this case the values the OP gives as output suggests that char is signed on their platform. I was just trying to explain to them how i ever ended up 'false'

Answer (score 0):

the loop termination condition here is ++i. There is no mystery about it. The loop will stop when i hits 0 (because the it will be 'false')

Comment: you answered your own question "So how does compiler decide which condition to consider because here other two appear as conditions". THe middle clause of the for loop is the termination test - ++i in your case. The fact that the other 2 clauses are also conditionals is irrelevant (but confusing to a human reader). The compiler simply produces code that executes the first and third clauses at the approairate time, its doesnt look at the result